# Will using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory get my application's base directory

Tags: c#, directory, console-application

Ok I have an application that will run on different servers.  I am using a X509certv2 in order to authenticate the app.  I currently have the cert in the project itself under the directory Cert.

[image]

**Code** **:**
I am trying to use the following code to get that cert file from that directory which is located in the project

```
string certfile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Certs\\"+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientCertificatePfx"];
```

**Result :** 
C:\Users\er4505\Downloads\newone\DHG_0365_Procs\bin\Debug\Certs\PKCS.pfx

**Main Objective:**
I would like to get the directory from the project itself, because it will be placed on a few servers and a absolute path will not cut it.

Comment: How about using "embedded resource"?

Comment: Used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory with this applications and have not had a problem with it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

The above snippet may help you narrow it down to your executing DLL. (typically could be ur bin folder or where u deploy ur DLL) See if that helps!

But, judging from your Results, it is already referring to ur bin, so this may again lead you to your Debug folder.

I suggest you go to the certificate properties by right clicking it and change the "Copy to Output Directory" attribute value to "Copy if Newer" This should also copy ur cert to your Output folder (bin) when u compile.  You should be able to access it from there !